# File download with nginx, django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, nginx, uwsgi, x-accel-redirect

I'm currently writing a small personal-use website served with nginx, utilizing uwsgi, django, and bootstrap.  All is going smoothly except for one issue that I cannot figure out.  I have download links (buttons) on the site, and when clicked, should initiate a file download.  Here is the view that is executed when a button is pressed:

```
@login_required
def download_file(request):
    '''
    downloads a file given a specified UUID
    '''

    if request.method == 'GET':
        file_uuid = request.GET['file_id']

        file_row = Files.objects.get(uuid=file_uuid)
        file_name = file_row.file_name

        response = HttpResponse()
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/media/files/%s' % file_name
        return response

    else:
        return redirect('/files')
```

/media/files is served directly by nginx as a internal location:

```
location /media/files/ {
   internal;
   alias /mnt/files/;
}
```

How this view is being called with an onclick event assigned to each button:

```
$('.download_btn').on('click',function(){
    download_file(this.id);
})

function download_file(uuid){
    $('.file_id').val(uuid);
    $('.get_file').submit();
}
```

I have a form with a single hidden field.  This gets set to the id (uuid) of the button that is pressed.

Pretty simple right?  My issue is that when the download button is pressed, the download is not initiated correctly.  The user is not prompted with a save dialog, nor does the file begin automatically downloading (Chrome or Safari).  Instead, in debug tools, I can see the file downloading to what seems to be local storage in the browser, or some memory location (these are large files; > 1GB).  I see the memory ballooning, and eventually the browser will crash.  Any clue what I'm doing wrong here?  Based on what I've been reading, this should be working without issue.

Comment: Just tried adding: `response['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'`  No change.

Comment: try do same but without html form - just virtual link to file. If user not logged оn - django return html, if logged on - django redirect request to web-server. Then browser detect that nginx return binary data and save it in normal way.

Comment: Just tried to have the redirect straight to /media/files/file_name and the exact same issue occurred.  I'm testing with Safari if that makes any difference.  Could it have anything to do with my mime.types settings in nginx?

Comment: Check your Nginx location. It should be:

    location ~ ^/media/files/ {
        internal;
        alias /mnt/files;
    }

Comment: Checked nginx, didn't change anything.  I did notice some odd behavior in the nginx logs though.  It appears almost that its returning the data, not as an attachment or download, but as browser content, which would explain the loading into memory that I'm seeing.